# Delete produces an exeption Java

Tags: java, android, android-room

In the app I create different tables with Room. I use one of them to save regions that users enter during the registration and then add these regions to a spinner in the registration form. In this fragment I use @Delete which worked just fine up to this day. I didn't change any logic or even accessed this fragment. 
It seems Room itself works fine when I comment out this Delete portion of the code.
Please,help!
Here is my code and the log.

```
@Dao
public interface RegionDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM Region")
    Cursor getAll();

    @Insert
    void insertAll(Region... regions);

    @Query("SELECT COUNT(*) from Region")
    int countRegions();

    @Delete
    void nukeTable(Region... regions);
}
```

**When the exepton occured I previosly had this code as a delete method as one of the answers on the site suggests but then changed it as the documentation suggests ,the result is the same

```
@Query("DELETE FROM Region")
    public void nukeTable();


    public class Fragment2 extends Fragment {

        AppDatabase myDB;
        .......
       @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup 
        container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           ..............................
            mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
            ..
            initDB();
            myDB.regionDao().nukeTable();
            if (myDB.regionDao().countRegions() == 0) {
                addRegion();
            } 
         @Override
         public void onDestroy() {

            super.onDestroy();
            myDB.close();
        }

        private void initDB() {
            myDB = Room.databaseBuilder(getContext(),
                    AppDatabase.class, 
       "DataBase").allowMainThreadQueries().build();

        }

        public void addRegion() {
            Region newRegion1 = new Region();
            Region newRegion2 = new Region();
            Region newRegion3 = new Region();
            Region newRegion4 = new Region();
            Region newRegion5 = new Region();
            Region newRegion6 = new Region();

            newRegion1.setRegion("Alaska");
            newRegion2.setRegion("Texas");
            newRegion3.setRegion("Columbia");
            newRegion4.setRegion("Utah");
            newRegion5.setRegion("California");
            newRegion6.setRegion("Florida");

            myDB.regionDao().insertAll(newRegion1);
            myDB.regionDao().insertAll(newRegion2);
            myDB.regionDao().insertAll(newRegion3);
            myDB.regionDao().insertAll(newRegion4);
            myDB.regionDao().insertAll(newRegion5);
            myDB.regionDao().insertAll(newRegion6);
        }
```

LOG:

```
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/arch/core/executor/AppToolkitTaskExecutor;
                                                                        at android.arch.persistence.room.InvalidationTracker.refreshVersionsAsync(InvalidationTracker.java:403)
                                                                        at android.arch.persistence.room.RoomDatabase.endTransaction(RoomDatabase.java:219)
                                                                        at com.anastacia.test_2.room.RegionDao_Impl.nukeTable(RegionDao_Impl.java:70)
                                                                        at com.anastacia.test_2.Fragments.Fragment2.onCreateView(Fragment2.java:74)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2354)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1419)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1740)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1809)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:799)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2580)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2367)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2322)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2229)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:700)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5791)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:762)
                                                                     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.arch.core.executor.AppToolkitTaskExecutor" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.anastacia.test_2-2/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.anastacia.test_2-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.anastacia.test_2-2/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.anastacia.test_2-2/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.anastacia.test_2-2/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.anastacia.test_2-2/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.anastacia.test_2-2/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.anastacia.test_2-2/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.anastacia.test_2-2/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.anastacia.test_2-2/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.anastacia.test_2-2/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.anastacia.test_2-2/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.anastacia.test_2-2/lib/arm64, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
                                                                        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                                                                        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
                                                                        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
                                                                        at android.arch.persistence.room.InvalidationTracker.refreshVersionsAsync(InvalidationTracker.java:403) 
                                                                        at android.arch.persistence.room.RoomDatabase.endTransaction(RoomDatabase.java:219) 
                                                                        at com.anastacia.test_2.room.RegionDao_Impl.nukeTable(RegionDao_Impl.java:70) 
                                                                        at com.anastacia.test_2.Fragments.Fragment2.onCreateView(Fragment2.java:74) 
                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2354) 
                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1419) 
                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1740) 
                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1809) 
                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:799) 
                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2580) 
                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2367) 
                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2322) 
                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2229) 
                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:700) 
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815) 
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104) 
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5791) 
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901) 
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:762) 
                                                                        Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.arch.core.executor.AppToolkitTaskExecutor
                                                                        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
                                                                        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
                                                                        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
                                                                        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
```

Comment: Have you tried to clean, invalidate caches and/or restart? If you didn't touch anything it's probably something related to AS cache.

Comment: Yes, I did all of these, nothing worked.
The main thing that is changed is I added multi-dexing into the project. 
Can it be related?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The log is referencing that could not find class **"android.arch.core.executor.AppToolkitTaskExecutor"**
this is a class from "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler", please check your gradle and make sure all your component dependencies are up to date to the latest version which is "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:**1.0.0-rc1**" as of today

You can check all the component dependency versions in the following hyperlink

[Adding Architecture Components to your Project - Google Developers](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/adding-components.html)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Actually, I had just one mismatch in my dependencies which the Studio didn't highlight! Thanks, that wasn't really smart of me))